# Solr UTC Datetime Retain Format in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data

I have a simple Java client that talks to a Solr endpoint. A query is executed and the fields all map to fields within my POJO. However, one of the Solr fields (config below) is seemingly being converted to a java.util.Date then a String before it makes it to my POJO. Is this behavior expected, and how can I keep everything as the literal String value being returned from Solr, or am I going to need to do some clunky conversions back to a UTC datetime string?

Solr is old, it’s 4.4.0, but I have no control over that and minimal control over any configurations. Spring-data-solr is 2.0.5.RELEASE.

My client:

```
private Cursor<SolrMetricRecord> querySolr(Query query) {
        Cursor<SolrMetricRecord> cur = null;
        try {
            cur = solrTemplate.queryForCursor(query, SolrMetricRecord.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception thrown querying Solr",e);
        }
        return cur;
    }

@Override
    public List<SolrMetricRecord> getSolrMetricsRecordsStartingAtAccessDate(String startingAccessDate) {
        
        if (startingAccessDate==null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Starting accessDate must be specified."); 
        
        Query query = new SimpleQuery();
        query.addCriteria(new Criteria(SOLR_FIELD_NAME_ACCESS_DATE).greaterThan(startingAccessDate));
        query.addSort(new Sort(SOLR_FIELD_NAME_ACCESS_DATE));
        query.setRows(1000);
        
        Cursor<SolrMetricRecord> cur = querySolr(query);

        return populateListFromCursor(cur);
    }

private List<SolrMetricRecord> populateListFromCursor(Cursor<SolrMetricRecord> cur) {
        if (cur==null) {
            logger.info("Null cursor returned from Solr query");
            return null;
        }

        if (cur.isClosed())
            logger.info("Cursor is closed... Call open()?");
        
        List<SolrMetricRecord> list = new ArrayList<SolrMetricRecord>();
        
        try {
            while (cur.hasNext()) {
                list.add(cur.next());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // This makes no sense...
            logger.debug("Exception thrown calling hasNext()",e);
        }
        
        return list;
    }
```

My POJO:

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "metrics")
public class SolrMetricRecord {

    @Id
    @Indexed(name = "id", type = "String")
    private String id;
    
    @Field("accessDate")
    private String accessDate;
    
// Other fields
```

The Solr field:

```
<field name="accessDate" type="datetime" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
...
<fieldtype name="datetime" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

What’s in Solr for accessDate:

2023-06-06T17:52:17.139Z

What I get back when I call the getter in Java:

Tue Jun 06 13:52:17 EDT 2023

Comment: you may need to change the pojo for the accessdate field with import java.util.Date;

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want it as a date, especially a java.util.Date. Keeping it as the string value Solr is providing is all I need, and I can do all the necessary comparisons that way.

Comment: then you need change the field type in solr as well as string fieldType?

Comment: I don't think I can do that without breaking other things consuming the service. It's looking more and more like I'm going to have to parse the Java date string, then convert it back to the UTC value, which is proving to be a pain in and of itself. I was just hoping there's some Spring configuration I could specify to make it return the string value from Solr. Nowhere am I asking for a date in the Java code.